# Additions to extraAllowedFileExtensions not showing up in the checkbox list

Tags: templating, assets, field

When adding `'extraAllowedFileExtensions' => 'css'` to `/craft/config/general.php` it doesn't show up in the list below `Restrict allowed file types?`. Am I missing something? Is it just not "restrictable" to an added filetype?

Answer (score 1):

It's not "restrictable", because you just added it. Why would you then go back and restrict it?

Using `extraAllowedFileExtensions` doesn't change the checkbox list at all. It simply allows you to upload files *in addition* to what is available on that list.

Comment: Gotcha, but what if you actually wanted to restrict to that single file type? So that a field can't be populated by other filetypes. Because if I then restrict to something like `Access` it won't let me upload the added file extension to that field, just `Access` files...

Comment: Two semi-related feature requests: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1584 and https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1511

Comment: Was just about to say, "sounds like a feature request" ;)

Comment: My wish: `'extraAllowedFileExtensions' => [ 'css': 'Stylesheet', 'hl3': 'Half-Life 3' ]`. Then there could be the checkboxes added to the "Restrict by type" part according to the name provided.